# Javascript to read site collection storage volume

Tags: 2013, javascript, storage

It is possible to read the storage Volume of a site collection with JavaScript?

Comment: For which version of SharePoint do you require this?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 onPrem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code after attaching jQuery library on page.

```
$(function(){
       $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/site/usage",
        type: "GET",               
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
             var percent = data.d.Usage.StoragePercentageUsed;
             percent = 100*percent;
             percent = percent;
             var storage = data.d.Usage.Storage;
             storage = storage/1073741824;
             storage = storage;
             alert("Total storage: "+((storage*100)/percent).toFixed(2)+"GB"); 
             alert("Storage used: "+storage.toFixed(2)+"GB");   
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    });    

});
```

**P.S.:** It will only show proper value if you have set "Quota Template" during site collection creation.

Hope this will help you.